# Error in sql syntax while trying to perform query

Tags: mysql

```
 INSERT INTO `2018_players`(`p_id`, `player_fname`, `player_lname`, `stats_id`, `home_id`) VALUES (
  (1, 'LeBron', 'James', 2, 3, 23),
  (2, 'Stephen', 'Curry', 4, 5, 30),
  (3, 'James', 'Harden', 6, 7, 13),
  (4, 'Giannis', 'Antekokounmpo', 8, 9, 34),
  (5, 'Paul', 'George', 10, 11, 13);
```

Server version: 5.7.23

1 error were found during analysis.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: You got a parentheses too much, near `VALUES`

Comment: One obvious error is the parenthesis after `VALUES`, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying 5 columns, but trying to insert 6 values per row, and there is an extra bracket after `VALUES`, you want something like:

```
 INSERT INTO `2018_players`(`p_id`, `player_fname`, `player_lname`, `stats_id`, `home_id`, `extra_column`) VALUES 
  (1, 'LeBron', 'James', 2, 3, 23),
  (2, 'Stephen', 'Curry', 4, 5, 30),
  (3, 'James', 'Harden', 6, 7, 13),
  (4, 'Giannis', 'Antekokounmpo', 8, 9, 34),
  (5, 'Paul', 'George', 10, 11, 13);
```